# Luke 8:42 "twelve" coincides with Luke 8:43 "twelve"?

Tags: luke

Luke 8:

> 40 Now when Jesus returned, a crowd welcomed him, for they were all expecting him. 41Then a man named Jairus, a synagogue leader, came and fell at Jesus’ feet, pleading with him to come to his house 42 because his only daughter, a girl of about **twelve**, was dying.
>
> As Jesus was on his way, the crowds almost crushed him. 43 And a woman was there who had been subject to bleeding for **twelve years**, but no one could heal her. 44 She came up behind him and touched the edge of his cloak, and immediately her bleeding stopped.

Are the two twelve's just coincident? Is there a significance?

Comment: Probably not; the fact that they were both females, and a twelve-year period appears in both accounts, might have been one of the author's reasons for grouping these two stories near one another within the gospel's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many similarities and differences in these two healings of the Daughter of Jairus and the bleeding woman, as recorded in Matt 9:18-26, Mark 5:23-43, Luke 8:41-46.  Here is a sample.

| Sick Woman | Sick/dead Girl |
| --- | --- |
| Chronic sickness | Acute sickness |
| Sick for 12 years | Girl 12 years old |
| Called a "daughter" (of Abraham) | Was a daughter of Jairus |
| Sought Jesus directly | Father sought Jesus |
| Woman's approach to Jesus was illegal | Girl's father's approach to Jesus was legal |
| Woman was an outcast (bleeding) | Daughter had social standing at the synagogue |
| Woman was very poor because she had spent everything to get well | The synagogue ruler was not poor and but asked Jesus to heal much earlier in the sickness |
| Healed by touching Jesus's cloak | Healed when Jesus touched her hand |
| Healed in public | Healed in private (home) |
| Woman approached from behind | Jesus approached the girl from the front |
| Jesus spoke to the woman after the healing | Jesus spoke to the girl before the healing |
| Jesus surrounded by a crowd and commotion | Jesus went to commotion at the house and told them to leave |
| Commotion consisted of the "press of the crowd" keen to be with Jesus | Commotion consisted of the wailing of a funeral |
| Woman told that her faith had healed her. | Jesus told the messengers that they should have faith and not be afraid |

... and so forth.  The three evangelists, Matthew, Mark and Luke combine these two stories because they are so inextricably linked and show Jesus' varied methods and compassion.  The 12 year element is just one of many that bind these two healing together.